# Proof: the element $0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ is unique.

Tags: solution-verification, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

If I symbolize the argument in First-Order logic, I think this would be the argument (the conclusion is an expansion of $\exists!$ definition):

$\exists z \forall x(x+z=x) \vdash \exists y(\forall x(x+y=x) \land \forall z(\forall x(x+z=x) \to y=z)$

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$
$
\fitch{1.\, \exists z \forall x(x+z=x)}{
  \fitch{2.\, a+0'=a}{
 \fitch{3.\, \neg(0 = 0')}{
 \fitch{4.\, \forall x(x+0=x)}{
 5.\, 0'+0=0' \Ae{3}
 6.\, 0=0 \qi{}
 7.\, 0+0'=0 \qe{5,2}
 8.\, 0'=0 \qe{6,4}
 9.\, \bot \ne{}
}\\
10.\, \bot \Ee{}
}\\
0=0'
}
}
$

I have as an axiom: $\exists z \forall x(x+z=x)$, used here as a premise.

The problem I have is that I cannot instantiate  *z* to $0$ (**step 4**), as it occurs in a previous undischarged assumptions (**step 3**).

Are there any routes to complete the proof and effectively use **Existential Elimination** ?

EDIT: based on comments, I rewrote the proof. I am a step forward, but still cannot close $\mathbf{\exists E}$ proof, since both $0$ and $0'$ appear in undischarged assumptions.

EDIT 2: 
$$
\fitch{1.\, \exists z \forall x(x+z=x)\\2.\, \forall x\forall y(x+y=y+x)}{
 \fitch{2.\, \forall x(x+0'=x)}{
 3.\, 0+0'=0 \Ae{1}
 \fitch{4.\, ¬(0=0')}{
 \fitch{5.\, \forall x(x+0=x)}{
 6.\, 0'+0=0' \Ae{4}
 7.\, 0+0'=0'+0 \Ae{2}
 8.\, 0+0'=0' \qe{6,5}
 9.\, 0=0' \qe{3,7}
 10.\, \bot \ne{4,8}
}\\
11.\, \bot \Ee{1,5-10}
}\\
12.\, 0=0' \IP{4-11}
}\\
13.\, \forall x(x+0'=x) \to 0=0' \ii{2-12}
14.\, \forall z(\forall x(x+z=x) \to 0=z) \Ai{13}
15.\, \exists y(\forall x(x+y=x) \land \forall z(\forall x(x+z=x) \to y=z) \Ei{14}
}
$$

Comment: $\exists !y [P(y)]$ is $\exists y[P(y) \land \forall z[P(z) \to z = y]$. In your case $P(y)$ is $\forall x[ x + y = x ]$, so your expansion is incorrect.

Comment: @Magdiragdag deleted. You were correct.

Comment: Your conclusion should be $\exists y \forall x(x+y=x \land \forall z(\color{red}{\forall x} \ x+z=x \to y=z))$ which is equivalent to $\exists y (\forall x \ x+y=x \land \forall z(\forall x \ x+z=x \to y=z))$, which as a symbolization I like better

Comment: Thank you very much, @Magdiragdag, Bram28 and David. Could you look at my updated proof ?

Comment: Just a question, @Bram28. In your first symbolisation of the conclusion, isn't inner _x_ (in red) clashing with outer _x_ ?

Comment: You still haven't fixed the statement you have to prove. And in line 3, instead of instantiating with an arbitrary element $a$, instantiate with $0$. Then, in line 5, don't instantiate with $a$, but with $0'$. You then need commutativity of $+$ to finish.

Comment: I am going to fix it in a moment. I forgot about that. And will try your suggestion. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, @Magdiragdag. I think I did it. Any improvements or corrections ?

Comment: @F.Zer No.It's true that the inner $x$'s are within thew scope of the outer quantifier, but since the inner $x$'s are quantified by the inner $x$'s and the others by the outer quantifier, and so there is no problem or conflict.

Comment: @Bram28, I see one problem. If I use Universal Instantiation with variable x (outer Universal Quantifier), I need to replace _every_ occurrence of _x_ that lies within its scope. That means the inner _x_ should be replaced, also. What do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second proof still not quite right ... you need to have:

$\forall x(x+0'=x) \land \forall z(\forall x(x+z=x) \to 0'=z)$

before introducing the existential at the end

... and so all that needs to go inside the subproof.  Here is a proof in Fitch. The $\forall \ I$ rule works a little differently than yours: it is looking for a subproof where you introduce a new constant, i.e. the analogue to 'Let $b$ be an arbitrary object':
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Going to rework it.